# Accessing original overwritten variable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have WPF window code and I want to change the window title, normally i can do

```
this.Title = "Bla"
```

But what if in xaml part of the window code, I have a text box named Title (Name="Title") which overrides the default window Title variable which sets the title of the window? How do I access the original window title variable without having to rename the textbox?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Just rename your TextBox like this "txtTitle"

Comment: I would expect that you'd get an error trying to call your `TextBox` `Title` as it introduces a naming conflict.  The solution when it hurts to do this is not to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First solution.*

You can use `base` keyword:

```
base.Title = "bla";
```

*Second solution.*

You can change window title in the `Loaded` event, by casting sender object to `Window`.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWindow.MainWindow"        
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="title" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="Title" MinWidth="100" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as Window).Title = "bla";
    }
}
```